# CodeIgniter PHP inserting image

Tags: php, html, image, codeigniter, directory

I have created a website using CodeIgniter, styled it using CSS and done the usual things. However one thing I can't seem to insert an image into the pages. I think I have to use an echo site URL method like I did with the CSS but it's still coming up with the broken link image. My directory is; application, css, images, js. The CSS works, why do the images not link?

The view page:

```
<head>

<link href="<?php echo base_url()."css/style.css";?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<title>Website Title</title> 

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
</head>


<div id="wrapper">

<body> 

<h1>Heading 1</h1>

<img src="<?php echo site_url('images/image_name.jpg'); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('/images/image_name.jpg'); ?>" />
```

In the header, you can use this by the way, which is a built in CodeIgniter function:

```
<?php echo link_tag('css/style.css'); ?>
```

Also, you shouldn't have a `div` wrapping the `body` tag.

It should be like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
```

Not the other way round.

Comment: yeah that worked, and i have swapped the div tag around

Answer (score 0):

When I use images in CodeIgniter I always set it up like this:

```
in config:
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/projectname/';

in view: 
    <img alt="" src="<?php echo BASE_URL(); ?>css/images/image_name.jpg" />
```

Tip: Check if your BASE_URL is ending with a slash ( / ) or not. I overlooked it once and it took me ages to find. :P

I hope this will help!